# Pandas 4 lists comparison

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am pretty new in python and have the following problem. I have a csv file which has 4 columns. I am ing the data into a dataframe by reading the csv file. I want to compare Date 1 and Date 2 and fill from date2 the missing values from date1. In addition, also the values from Values2 to Values1.

I have a csv file which looks like the following:

```
Date 1;Values 1;Date 2;Values 2
07.08.2017;-0,52;07.08.2017;-0,52
04.08.2017;-1,30;04.08.2017;-1,3
03.08.2017;-0,40;03.08.2017;-0,3995
02.08.2017;-0,43;02.08.2017;-0,4285
01.08.2017;-0,46;01.08.2017;-0,46
31.07.2017;-0,48;31.07.2017;-0,3625
27.07.2017;-0,42;28.07.2017;-1,25
26.07.2017;-0,42;27.07.2017;-0,41
25.07.2017;-0,41;26.07.2017;-0,415
24.07.2017;-0,40;25.07.2017;-0,4085
21.07.2017;-1,31;24.07.2017;-0,4
```

I tried to code as the following but not succesful and I receive an error message:

> KeyError: 'Date 1'

The code looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

csv_loader = pd.read_csv('File1.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()
csv_loader.reset_index()
print(csv_loader)
print("-----------------------------------------------")

test = set(csv_loader["Date 1"]).intersection(csv_loader["Date 2"])
```

The output should look like the following:

```
Date 1        Values 1    Date 2       Values 2                                  
07.08.2017    -0,52       07.08.2017   -0,52
04.08.2017    -1,30       04.08.2017   -1,3
03.08.2017    -0,40       03.08.2017   -0,3995
02.08.2017    -0,43       02.08.2017   -0,4285
01.08.2017    -0,46       01.08.2017   -0,46
31.07.2017    -0,48       31.07.2017   -0,3625
28.07.2017    -1,25       28.07.2017   -1,25
27.07.2017    -0,41       27.07.2017   -0,41
26.07.2017    -0,42       26.07.2017   -0,415
25.07.2017    -0,41       25.07.2017   -0,4085
24.07.2017    -0,40       24.07.2017   -0,4
21.07.2017    -1,31       21.07.2017   -1,31
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: @canis, what is not clear from your side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could come close to the desired result by performing an [outer-merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra). Then using [AMC's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634702/190597), call `combine_first` to fill in the missing data:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_loader = pd.read_csv('File1.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';')
df1 = csv_loader[['Date 1', 'Values 1']]
df2 = csv_loader[['Date 2', 'Values 2']]
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Date 1', right_on='Date 2', how='outer')
mask = pd.isnull(result[['Date 1', 'Date 2']])

for col in ['Date', 'Values']:
    a, b = '{} 1'.format(col), '{} 2'.format(col)
    result[a] = result[a].combine_first(result[b])
    result[b] = result[b].combine_first(result[a])
print(result)

missing = {col:result.loc[mask[col], col] for col in mask}
for col in missing:
    print('missing from {}:\n{}'.format(col, missing[col]))
```

yields

```
        Date 1 Values 1      Date 2 Values 2
0   07.08.2017    -0,52  07.08.2017    -0,52
1   04.08.2017    -1,30  04.08.2017     -1,3
2   03.08.2017    -0,40  03.08.2017  -0,3995
3   02.08.2017    -0,43  02.08.2017  -0,4285
4   01.08.2017    -0,46  01.08.2017    -0,46
5   31.07.2017    -0,48  31.07.2017  -0,3625
6   27.07.2017    -0,42  27.07.2017    -0,41
7   26.07.2017    -0,42  26.07.2017   -0,415
8   25.07.2017    -0,41  25.07.2017  -0,4085
9   24.07.2017    -0,40  24.07.2017     -0,4
10  21.07.2017    -1,31  21.07.2017    -1,31
11  28.07.2017    -1,25  28.07.2017    -1,25

missing from Date 2:
10    21.07.2017
Name: Date 2, dtype: object
missing from Date 1:
11    28.07.2017
Name: Date 1, dtype: object
```

---

Note that `index_col=0` causes `read_csv` to make the first column the index.
So `Date 1` becomes the name of the index, not a column of the DataFrame.
Notice how `Date 1` appears on a line by itself, below the column names:

```
In [67]: csv_loader
Out[67]: 
           Values 1      Date 2 Values 2
Date 1                                  
07.08.2017    -0,52  07.08.2017    -0,52
04.08.2017    -1,30  04.08.2017     -1,3
...
```

To leave `Date 1` as a column, remove `index_col=0`.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. But somehow i realize that with my code I did not received the solution I wanted. Do you see it above?

Comment: Cool that's it what I was lookng for. One more questions. Is it possible to get a seperate dataframe which shows the Date 1 and Date 2 which were missing as two columns in the new Dataframe? That would be sooo helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `mask = pd.isnull(result[['Date 1', 'Date 2']])` to record which dates were missing. Do this before filling in the missing dates of course :) Then after the missing dates have been filled in, you can retrieve the missing dates with `result.loc[mask[col], col]`. I've edited the code above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you'll need to remove is the dropna() function. Currently you are removing all rows that are blank.

Then, you can use this:

```
csv_loader["combined_date"] = csv_loader["Date 1"].combine_first(csv_loader["Date 2"])
```

This will create a new column, combined_date, which has all values from Date 1 and any values from Date 2 are input into the blanks from Date 1.

I don't know how your df looks like with blanks, but something like:

```
  Date 1         Date 2       combined_date
08.08.2017     08.17.2017      08.08.2017
   nan         02.02.2017      02.02.2017
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. But I also need to fill then the Values from2 to Value 1 for that date. In addition, can I write the dates which were missing in a separate column?

Comment: For Value 2 and Value 1, you'll want to do the same thing, just adapt the column names (e.g. Date 1 -> Value 1). As far as writing the missing dates, you can, but I don't see how that would be useful, because if you create a new column with the combined date/value, you'll be keeping Date 1 and Value 1, which will have the null values. If you want to create a new DF with the nulls, you can do:

    new_df = csv_loader[csv_loader.isnull()]